# Why isn't my definition for OnCollisionEnter() being used?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I have a character that a Boolean flag which determines whether or not he is jumping (if he is jumping, he cannot jump again). When he jumps, the jump flag is set to true, and when he collides with something it is set back to false (so he can jump again).

However, he only jumps once, and jump stays true even when it's supposed to reset to false. Why is this so? My definition for `OnCollisionEnter()` is supposed to reset the flag.

```js
var trump;
var jump = false;

function Start() {
// Assigns the Rigidbody to a variable
trump = GetComponent(Rigidbody2D);
// Variable Switches:

}

function OnCollisionEnter() {
    jump = false;
    trump.velocity.y = 0;
    trump.velocity.x = 0;
}

function FixedUpdate() {
    trump.velocity.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 10;
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) && (jump == false)) {
        trump.AddForce(Vector2(0, 10), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        jump = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Based on an answer given I tried adding the `Collision` parameter to `OnCollisionEnter()`, but it still doesn't look like the function is being called after I added a `Debug.Log()` inside of it to check. Is there something else wrong?

```js
function OnCollisionEnter(collision: Collision) {
    jump = false;
    Debug.log("He Hit The Wall");
    trump.velocity.y = 0;
    trump.velocity.x = 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: <joke>It's Trump. He doesn't let other people tell him what to do :-p</joke> - Seriously, though, `Why won't Trump jump more than once?` is by far the funniest and craziest question title I've seen in a while ;-)

Comment: This one caught my eye for that reason. XP But I'd really like to edit the title to be a more useful/searchable question for the future...

Comment: @serlite - always just click edit anytime you see an edit to make

Comment: @Number1son100 - you *can not* use "unityscript". It is deprecated, does not work, and is being removed from Unity.  Fortunately c# is far easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function signature for `OnCollisionEnter()` is incorrect. When defining these MonoBehaviour-specific functions, it is imperative that the name and parameters of the function match that shown in the documentation. Otherwise, the MonoBehaviour won't recognize them and the function won't be called when expected.

In this case, [`OnCollisionEnter()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) requires a `Collision` parameter:

```js
function OnCollisionEnter(collision: Collision) {
    jump = false;
    trump.velocity.y = 0;
    trump.velocity.x = 0;
}
```

*Note: The above was written before the question was edited to implement the suggestion - before, `OnCollisionEnter()` was being defined without a parameter.*

However, in your case that isn't the only problem - you're using Unity's 2D physics, which means you should actually be using the 2D variant of the function: [`OnCollisionEnter2D`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html), which also takes a slightly different parameter of a `Collision2D`.

So you would need:

```js
function OnCollisionEnter2D(collision: Collision2D) {
    jump = false;
    trump.velocity.y = 0;
    trump.velocity.x = 0;
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: @Number1son100 Hey, I took a closer look at your problem and you're right, there was something else wrong. I have updated my answer to reflect this, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Do you want double jump?

Comment: Thank you! Though how would I do that?

Comment: @Number1son100 Glad I could help out! I'll try to answer for Barış - in the case of double jump, you'd just have to change your logic somewhat to use a counter (like `var jumpsRemaining = 2`) for tracking the jumping, rather than a Boolean flag. Only allow jumping when `jumpsRemaining > 1`, and with every subsequent jump, subtract 1 from it. Then, reset it to the desired number of jumps (like 2) when you collide with something.